# POST request fails to interact with site

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to login to a site called grailed.com and follow a certain product. The code below is what I have tried.

The code below succeeds in logging in with my credentials. However whenever I try to follow a product (the id in the payload is the id of the product) the code runs without any errors but fails to follow the product. I am confused at this behavior. Is it a similar case to Instagram (where Instagram blocks any attempt to interact programmatically with their site and force you to use their API (grailed.com does not have a API for the public to use AFAIK)

I tried the following code (which looks exactly like the POST request sent when you follow on the site).

```
headers/data defined here
r = requests.Session()
v = r.post("https://www.grailed.com/api/sign_in", json=data,headers = headers)

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.grailed.com',
    'method': 'POST',
    "path": "/api/follows",
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-amplitude-id": "1547853919085",
    "x-api-version": "application/grailed.api.v1",
    "x-csrf-token": "9ph4VotTqyOBQzcUt8c3C5tJrFV7VlT9U5XrXdbt9/8G8I14mGllOMNGqGNYlkES/Z8OLfffIEJeRv9qydISIw==",
    "origin": "https://www.grailed.com",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
}
payload = {
    "id": "7917017"
}
b = r.post("https://www.grailed.com/api/follows",json = payload,headers = headers)
```

Comment: Please provide the request details of both the login and the product follow.

Comment: The fact is CSRF tokens were explicit built to prevent these kind of usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If API is not designed to be public, you are most likely missing csrf token in your follow headers.
You have to find an CSRF token, and add it to `/api/follows` POST.
taking fast look at code, this might be hard as everything goes inside javascript.

Comment: There is a CSRF token in the headers. But the habdling might still be wrong. It has to be retrieved from the site abd can't be copied from somewhere.

Comment: There is a CSRF Token in the requests. However none of them match the one used in the follow POST request. Can any CSRF token passed in the cookie be used?

Comment: As I checked before - tokens on this page are injected in JS, you have to dig in there.